# A non-cyclic Artinian module has at least two distinct minimal (simple) submodule.

Tags: ring-theory, modules, artinian

My Question: A non-cyclic Artinian module has at least two distinct minimal (simple) submodule.

My attempt: Let $M$ be a non-cyclic Artinian $R$-module. Then there exists two nonzero element $x,y\in M$ such that $Rx\nsubseteq Ry$ and $Ry\nsubseteq Rx$. Hence, by Zorns Lemma, $M$ has two distinct minimal submodules as $M$ is Artinian.

What is wrong hare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are taking a lot of liberties with your assertion.

Why do such $x,y$ exist?

Then why do you think that means there are distinct minimal submodules? It isn’t clear.

Why are you using Zorn’s lemma? You have both the DCC, already: you don’t need Zorn.  And it’s not clear how you were applying it anyway.

—-

Let $R=\mathbb R[x,y,z]/(x^2,y^2,xz,yz,z^2-xy)$.  It is known that $R$ is Artinian and has a simple socle, and hence a unique minimal ideal contained in all other nonzero ideals. It is also not a principal ideal ring. So if we take $M$ to be any nonprincipal ideal, we have a counterexample.

—-
Eric Wofsey points out in my comments:
$\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ works for the same reasons!

Comment: Or how about just $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey yeah that’s even simpler, and for the same reasons! It didn’t occur to me.  Hope you don’t mind if I append it.

Comment: If I replace Artinian with module of finite composition length,  Is the result true? That is, a non-cyclic module with finite composition length has at least two distinct minimal (simple) submodules.  Please reply.

Comment: @bipin the counterexamples give are finite composition length, so no.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.